# How to solve this step and are there any tips for this method?

Tags: inequality, mixing-variables

This is the problem:
Let $x,y,z$ be real number, prove that:
$(x+y)^4 +(y+z)^4 +(z+x)^4 -\frac{4}{7} (x^4+y^4+z^4) \geq 0$. (Vietnam TST 1996)

All the solutions I found are very complicated and not able to think about during the test, so I decide to solve it by myself.

Solution:

I put: $f(x;y;z)=(x+y)^4 +(y+z)^4 +(z+x)^4 -\frac{4}{7} (x^4+y^4+z^4)$

So: $f(\frac{x+y}{2};\frac{x+y}{2};z)=(a+b)^4+(c+\frac{a+b}{2})^4+(c+\frac{a+b}{2})^4-\frac{4}{7}((\frac{a+b}{2})^4+(\frac{a+b}{2})^4+c^4)$

In this method, I tried to make: $f(x;y;z) \geq f(\frac{x+y}{2};\frac{x+y}{2};z) \Leftrightarrow f(x;y;z) - f(\frac{x+y}{2};\frac{x+y}{2};z) \geq0$

And I put $x,y,z$ into this inequality and this is what I got  :

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2[(x+z)^2+(x+z)(y+z)+(y+z)^2+z(x+y+2z)]+\frac{2}{7}(x-y)^2[-t(x+y)-t^2-(y^2+xy+x^2)] \geq 0$

where $t=\frac{x+y}{2}$

Can anyone help me with the next step with natural solution please? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Have you seen [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h497708p2796235)?

Comment: How can you find this inequality on AOPS? :) Please show me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MV helps.

If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negatives, so our inequality is obvious.

Let there be negative variables.

Since our inequality is not changed after substitutions $x\rightarrow-x$, $y\rightarrow-y$ and $z\rightarrow-z$, it's enough to prove our inequality for $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$ and $z\leq0$.

Now, replace $z$ on $-z$ and we need to prove that $f(x,y,z)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x,y,z)=(x-z)^4+(y-z)^4+(x+y)^4-\frac{4}{7}(x^4+y^4+z^4)$$ for non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$.

1. $z\geq\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\right)(x+y).$

Thus, $$f(x,y,z)-f\left(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x+y}{2},z\right)=3(x-y)^2\left(z^2-(x+y)z+\frac{7x^2+10xy+7y^2}{56}\right)=$$
$$=3(x-y)^2\left(\left(z-\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2-\frac{7x^2+18xy+7y^2}{56}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq3(x-y)^2\left(\frac{(x+y)^2}{7}-\frac{7x^2+18xy+7y^2}{56}\right)=\frac{3(x-y)^4}{56}\geq0,$$ which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for $x=y$, which gives a true inequality(see my previous solution).

2. $z\leq\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\right)(x+y).$

In this cases it's enough to prove that $$(x-z)^4+(y-z)^4+(x+y)^4\geq\frac{4}{7}\left(x^4+y^4+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\right)^4(x+y)^4\right)$$ and since $$(x+y)^4\geq x^4+y^4,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$3>4\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt7}\right)^4$$ or
$$355>88\sqrt7,$$ which is true because
$$355>88\sqrt9>88\sqrt7.$$

Comment: It seem difficult, thank you a lot for your solution!

Comment: Yes, I agree. By using $uvw$ it's much more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your method (Mixing Variables method) is not so good here because we need to work with real numbers.

I think the best way here it's using $uvw$.

Indeed, this inequality is fourth degree, which says it's a linear inequality of $xyz$ and from here by $uvw$ it's enough to check $y=z=1$ (for $y=z=0$ our inequality is obviously true), which gives $$5x^4+28x^3+42x^2+28x+59\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$5x^4+28x^3+42x^2+28x+59=5\left(x^2+\frac{14}{5}x-\frac{1}{5}\right)^2+\frac{6}{5}(2x+7)^2>0.$$
About $uvw$ see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: It is so good! Thanks a lot! Can you continue my solution, because this is the request from my teacher :(, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Remark*: Here is an alternative proof.

Since the inequality does not change if $(x, y, z)$
is substituted with $(-x, -y, -z)$,
we assume that at most one of $x, y, z$ is negative.

If $x, y, z \ge 0$, clearly the inequality is true.

It remains to prove the case that $x
\ge y \ge 0$ and $z < 0$ (due to symmetry).

Since the inequality is homogeneous, assume that $z = -1$. It suffices to prove that
$$(x + y)^4 + (y - 1)^4 + (x - 1)^4 - \frac47(x^4 + y^4 + 1) \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

**Case 1**: $x \ge 1$

Using $(x + y)^4 - x^4 \ge (1 + y)^4 - 1^4$ (easy), we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS}_{(1)} &= (x + y)^4 - x^4 + \frac37x^4 + (y - 1)^4 + (x - 1)^4 - \frac47(y^4 + 1)\\
 &\ge (1 + y)^4 - 1^4 + \frac37 + (y - 1)^4 + (1 - 1)^4 - \frac47(y^4 + 1)\\
 &= (1 + y)^4 + (y-1)^4 - \frac87 - \frac47y^4 \\
 &\ge 2 + 2y^4 - \frac87 - \frac47y^2\\
 & > 0
\end{align*}
where we use $(1+y)^4 + (1 - y)^4 \ge 2 + 2y^4$ (easy).

**Case 2**: $x < 1$

We have
\begin{align*}
 \mathrm{LHS}_{(1)} &\ge \frac{(x + y + 1 - y)^4}{8} + (x - 1)^4 - \frac47(x^4 + x^4 + 1) \\
 &= \frac{(1+x)^4}{8} + (1-x)^4 - \frac87x^4 - \frac47\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use $a^4 + b^4 \ge (a + b)^4/8$
for all $a, b \ge 0$ (using the power mean inequality).

We are done.

Comment: what a beautiful solution! thanks alot!

Comment: Can you continue my solution, because this is the request from my teacher :(, thanks!

Comment: how can you assume $z=-1$ what if $z=1,2,3$

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát We assume that at most one of $x, y, z$ is negative. There are two cases. (1) $x, y, z \ge 0$. (2) Exactly one of $x, y, z$ is negative. We assume that $z < 0$.

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát As regards your approach, when $x = 1, y = 3, z = -1$, we have $f(x;y;z) < f(\frac{x+y}{2};\frac{x+y}{2};z)$, right?

Comment: yes, I understand it now! Thanks!

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát You are welcome.

Comment: Sorry, can you let me know the name of your method:) Thanks!

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát I don't know the name.

Comment: Can I put $z=-2$ or any negative number?

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát You can set $z$ equal to any negative number. For example, consider the inequality $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$ for $x, y > 0$. Since it is homogeneous, you can set $y = 1$ and go to prove $x^2 + 1 \ge 2x$. Surely, you can set $y = 2, 2.1, \pi$ etc.